# Undeleting Google Calendar Event

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I have a c# app which creates events in google calendar.  For its own purposes, it controls the event's UID, and sometimes wants to delete and recreate events.

When trying to recreate an event with the same UID as a deleted event, it gets "The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict."

I can see the deleted events by apending "?showdeleted=true&showhidden=true" to a request URL.

However I do not see anything in the API which allows me to undelete deleted events after retrieving them.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

Trying Jay's suggesting I have something like

```
var service = new CalendarService();
service.setUserCredentials("XXX", "XXX");
var query = new CalendarQuery { Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/owncalendars/full") };
var cal = service.Query(query).Entries
    .Select (e => new { Title = e.Title.Text, Uri = e.SelfUri, 
        Id = e.SelfUri.Content.Split('/').Last () } )
    .Single (e => e.Title == calendarName);
var eventQuery = new EventQuery(string.Format(@"http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/{0}/private/full?showdeleted=true&showhidden=true", cal.Id));
var evs = service.Query(eventQuery).Entries.Cast<EventEntry>().ToList();
evs[0].Status = EventEntry.EventStatus.CONFIRMED;
service.Update(ev[0]);
```

And it is giving me "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

Comment: should that last line be service.Update(evs[0]);  ? It looks like you're missing the s in evs.

Comment: also, if you already know the event ID, there's no reason to do a Query first, you should be able to just submit the update/patch with the change to status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Is due to the `EventEntry.EditUri` not being able to find the deleted / hidden events.

This can be fixed by appending "?showdeleted=true&showhidden=true" to the `EditUri`, before the `EntryEvent.Update`.

Something along the lines of:

```
var evs = service.Query(eventQuery).Entries.Cast<EventEntry>().ToList();
evs[0].Status = EventEntry.EventStatus.CONFIRMED;
evs[0].EditUri.Content = evs[0].EditUri.Content + "?showdeleted=true&showhidden=true";
evs[0].Update();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can undelete [an event](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) by changing it's `status` attribute from `cancelled` to `confirmed`

You can try this for yourself with an [events.patch()](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) operation in the [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/calendar.events.patch?calendarId=%253CCALENDAR%20ID%20HERE%253E&eventId=%253CEVENT%20ID%20HERE%253E&_h=5&resource=%257B%250A%20%20%2522status%2522%253A%20%2522confirmed%2522%250A%257D&). You'll need to turn on OAuth authorization and then input the calendar and event IDs.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work (anymore?)

Comment: Has just tried it and it worked

Comment: Note the caveats in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#status): "Such cancelled events will eventually disappear, so do not rely on them being available indefinitely. Deleted events are only guaranteed to have the id field populated."

Answer (score 0):

The patch operation on the status property seems to fail after deleting/cancelling an event with a 403 error on events that have been deleted some time ago. Setting the status to "cancelled" or deleting the event and then followed by setting the status to "confirmed" for a fresh event worked for me. This behavior is in accordance with the API documentation: "Such cancelled events will eventually disappear, so do not rely on them being available indefinitely. Deleted events are only guaranteed to have the id field populated.".

Joerg