# How to delete events permanently?

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I'm building a synchronization tool that upload the events available on the database, on a specific Google calendar via OAauth2.
Now the problem is this:

If the user remove an event I saw that Google Calendar doesn't remove it really. Infact trying to get a list of deleted event:

```
var service = authentication.GetService();

var request = service.Events.List("primary");
request.ShowDeleted = true;

var events = request.Execute();

foreach (var myEvent in events.Items)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Event => [ID]" + myEvent.Id );
     Console.WriteLine("description => " + myEvent.Description);
}
```

Now this return a list of all deleted events, but the problem is that this entries doesn't exist on my trash of Google Calendar.

So how can I recover it?

Comment: Try to check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188681/undeleting-google-calendar-event?) and this [thread](http://googleappstroubleshootinghelp.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-delete-event-on-google-calendar.html) if it can help you ;)

Comment: @KENdi so I guess that if I set the status of deleted event as completed I can add an event with the same id? This is non very clear for me.